# Current directory with OS.COMMAND

Tags: jtag, trace32, lauterbach

I'm trying to run a script(on OS level) (and not block until its return) from T32 using OS.Command, but when I do I get `'\\somepath'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.`

I want to run my command in the same directory as the scrip that calls it. OS.Hidden seems to work that way, but seems to block until the call is returned.

Answer (score 1):

In your script you can get the directory in which the current script is located with function OS.PPD(). Assign the value of this function to a PRACTICE macro and use it with OS.COMMAND
Like this:

```
LOCAL &ppd
&ppd=os.ppd()
OS.Command start "myTitle" "&ppd\myProgram.exe"
```